# Compiling and Exceuting via command line error with Hermit Reasoner using java

Tags: java, semantics

To follow the how to compile and run the Hermit Reasoner, I downloaded the file(`Hermit.zip`) and downloaded the source code for `Demo.java` and placed it inside my folder. I get this error when i try to follow this instruction on the Hermit website. `javac -cp HermiT.jar Demo.java`

```
javac -cp .;Hermit.jar Demo
error: Class names, 'Demo', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error
```

I need help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

`javac` is the command to **compile** `.java` files into `.class` files.

A `.jar` file is an archive which already contains `.class` files, so you don't need to compile it, you just need to run it.

The command to **run** java is `java` not `javac`.

Alternatively, if you are **compiling** in fact, then you need to specify `.java` as part of the file's name.